# How does spike -g works?

Tags: riscv

I built the riscv toolchain from the riscv-tools master branch.

When I do

> spike -h

It informs me about a -g option that should trace the histogram of PCs

I tried

> spike -g pk hello

I saw no special output nor files where the trace is saved.

So my question is, is the -g option supported yet? if yes how do we use it ?

Are the spike options documented elsewhere than here ?
http://riscv.org/download.html#tab_isa-sim

In the event that I am able to run spike with -g option, what kind of trace ouput format should I expect to see ?

Answer (score 1):

When compiling spike, you should pass *--enable-histogram* to *configure*. Then re-run *make* and *make install*. In general, you can see all of these extra options if you do

```
> ./configure --help
```